# How to install MQTT cordova plugins in VS.Net 2015

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova, ngcordova

I am new to cordova development, so I was wondering if someone can help me out here.

I am trying to develop a sample cordova application which will talk to mosquito server.

I have tried to make use of the plugin [here](https://github.com/arcoirislabs/mqtt-cordova) but looks like this is not working as there is a java file its trying to copy which is not available

```
<source-file src="src/android/Mqtt.java" target-dir="src/com/arcoirislabs/mqttcont" />
```

and also I think there is an error in the way it generated the url to connect in mqtt.js

```
if (data.secure) {
      dataUrl = "ssl://" + data.url  + data.port;
} else {
     dataUrl = "tcp://" + data.url + data.port;
};
```

I believe it should be something like `dataUrl = "tcp://" + data.url + ':' + data.port;`

however fixing this and commenting the above source-file out didn't help. So I was wondering if anyone has an working example of this MQTT example on the Cordova,/VS.net 2015.

BTW I am using AngularJS ToDO App for my example, not sure if that is an issue though, the code to publish looks like this:

```
ToDoCtrl.prototype.publishMqtt = function () {
        mqtt.publish({
            url: "localhost",
            topic: "Kiran/Temp/PNW6",
            secure: false,
            qos: "0",
            clientId: "SampleJavaV3_",
            port: "1883",
            message: "23.4",
            cleanSession: true,
            username: null,
            password: null,
            debug: true,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    };
```

the error I see in the following line in mqtt.js

```
cordova.exec(function (response) {
            data.success(response)
        }, function (error) { data.error(error); }, "MqTTPlugin", "publish", [dataUrl, data.clientId, quietM, data.username, data.password, cleanSes, data.topic, data.qos, data.message]);
```

it complains that

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'publish' of undefined
  at Object.module.exports.exec (http://localhost:4400/ripple/assets/ripple.js:40:29342)
  at Object.sero.publish (http://localhost:4400/plugins/com.arcoirislabs.plugin.mqtt/www/mqtt.js:38:17)
  at ToDoCtrl.publishMqtt (http://localhost:4400/scripts/controllers/toDoCtrl.js:86:11)
```

I can also see that there is a phone gap plugin [here](http://git.eclipse.org/c/paho/org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.javascript.git/about/?h=master) but I am unable to understand how this can be used in a VS.Net cordova application.

Regards
Kiran

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I am too late to answer this question. I am the original maintainer of the plugin. Please use our new plugin. It is working fine. Although we are updating the plugin regularly to add new features and platforms. It wasn't working fine at that time because the library need was not included in it. Now we are totally compatible with Gradle system and the underlying library is too good than the latter library used (which was by the way Eclipse Paho).
Let me know if there are any issues or suggestion.